# How can I change React Material-ui Drawer menu items spacing?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, components, material-ui

I'm trying to use Material-UI for the first time on a React project.  I have put together the AppBar to call Drawer and a list of menu items appear from the sidebar.  The problem I'm facing is that they have giant margin-top spacing.

Example of the spacing

```
Close (X)








About









Contact
```

I would like this all next to each other, one by one.

```
Close (X)
About 
Contact
```

I'm not sure what is causing the extra spacing.  I put together a similar mock up to the design I'm using now and the spacing was normal.  I have included the full component below.

## Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Redirect, IndexRoute, Link, hashHistory } from 'react-router'; 
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar'
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu'
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem'
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'

class AppBars extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props) 
            this.state = {
                open: false
            }
    }

    //toggleDrawer = () => this.setState({open: !this.state.open});

    toggleDrawer() {
        this.setState({
            open: !this.state.open,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <AppBar
                    title="Advanced Surface Innovations"
                    onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)} 
                />
                <Drawer open={this.state.open} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
                    <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
                    CLOSE ( X )
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}><Link to="/"> 
                        <FlatButton label="Home" primary={true} />
                    </Link>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}><Link to="/About"> 
                        <FlatButton label="About" primary={true} />
                    </Link>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}><Link to ="/Contact"> 
                        <FlatButton label="Contact" primary={true} />
                    </Link>
                    </MenuItem>
                </Drawer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class NavBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            nav: ''
        }
    }

    handleScroll(event) {
        console.log('handleScroll invoked');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount invoked');
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount invoked');
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <AppBars />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: I did a quick test to see if a drawer would render menu items in the way you mentioned, but I was not able to reproduce that large spacing issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to enclose your `MenuItem`s in a `Menu` block:

```
<Drawer open={this.state.open} onToggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
  <Menu onItemTouchTap={this.toggleDrawer.bind(this)}>
    <MenuItem >
      CLOSE ( X )
    </MenuItem>
    …
  </Menu>
</Drawer>
```

This also spares you from repeating the `onTouchTap` code on every item.

Also I'd use the route links as a prop to `MenuItem` instead of as children. That way the whole item will be clickable (otherwise it will only be the link text) and you don't need to style it as a button:

```
<MenuItem primaryText="Home" containerElement={<Link to="/">} />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had some issues finding out how to accomplish a dense listing of MenuItem's with MenuIcon. Looking at MenuItem source revealed I can
affect the spacing using 'lineHeight'. But there is a minimum limit to the spacing determined by 'minHeight'. So by setting minHeight less or equal to the desired lineHeight the appearance adapted to my needs.

```
const denseStyle = {
  minHeight:"10px",
  lineHeight: "25px",      // Smaller: Height of menu item row
  fontSize: "12px",        // Smaller font
  // color:"#0000ff"
};
```

So for every menu item a styling:

`<MenuItem style={denseStyle} onClick={`.......

Also in my case the three-dot-icon for the IconMenu was only partially visible in my slightly height reduced table listing,

`<TableRow style={{height:"20px"}}>`......

but using a negative top margin it displayed fully:

`<IconMenu style={{ marginTop: "-12px" }}`.......

Comment: This is pretty close.  At least I can kinda of control he height of the line spaces in between links with it.  Still no good solution so far though